# Удалить/Добавить класс при клике (Анимация)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Как удалить один класс и добавить другой при клике, при повторном клике обратные действия совершить?
Возможно ли добавить анимацию при переключении классов? (toggleClass)

Comment: Нужно повесить обработчик события на интересующий Вас блок, и при клике, задать/удалить этому блоку интересующий класс

Comment: Это я понимаю. Добавляется класс, удаляется предыдущий. А вот при повторном нажатии как выполнять обратные действия

Comment: Воспользуйтесь методом `toggle`. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList. Чтобы получить более точный ответ, нужно задать более точный вопрос: показать верстку, пример кода своих попыток реализации

Comment: Спасибо. Возможно ли добавить анимацию при переключении классов?

Comment: Смотря что изменяется, при переключении класса. Есть свойства, которые нельзя анимировать. Например, `display`

Comment: Анимация на подобие slide

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, что Вы подразумеваете по словом `slide`, то  `slide` может быть и без анимации. .....Здесь не приняты развернутые дискуссии, на разные темы. Задавайте отдельный вопрос, но помните, что здесь любят вопросы по конкретной проблеме.

Answer (score 1):

Допустим есть элемент с классом test1, данная конструкция при клике на нем будет менять класс test1 на test2 и наоборот:

```
    $(".test1, .test2").on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("test1 test2");
    });
```

Анимацию же можно прописать в CSS стилях данных двух классов, например, самое простое — плавное изменение цвета шрифта:

```
.test1,.test2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-transition: color 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: color 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: color 1s ease-out;
    transition: color 1s ease-out;
}
.test1 {
    color: red;
}
.test2 {
    color: green;
}
```